# computer simulates attack and freezes websites

Tags: freeze, anti-virus, website

My Dads computer keeps simulating attacks (beeping) and then freezes on certain websites but also random new  sites we go to. It used to work just fine on those sites but all of a sudden started to act that weird. As soon as you disconnect the internet it unfreezes and works again. When going back online it sometimes works fine or comes back when trying to continue on the site.

We've deleting cookies, ran and updating the antivirus programm and tryied using different browsers so far nothing helped.

If anyone has any advice on what it is and how to solve it I would greatly appreciate it. 
I have no idea anymore of what I could try to solve the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: More information on the actual problem is required to help you.  Is all your software using the current revision?

Comment: There is no more information I could give you on that problem. All the software is using current revision.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/), it's a good (there's a free version), anti malware program which should find whatever has infected the PC.

Failing that, just backup your data and wipe the PC. Reinstalling is often much quicker and easier than trying to completely remove malware, as you can often never be sure you have removed it all.

Comment: We tried Malwarebytes but it did not change anything. I Would like to try to avoid whiping the PC but mayb that's the only option we have. Thanks!

Comment: In that case I would still advise wiping. Past experience has taught me that the time it takes to backup, wipe and restore, is much much faster than the time it takes to remove the malware, plus you can be sure it is gone if you wipe it.